# Problems with ajax of the routing datatable in Api.php with post method

Tags: ajax, laravel, datatables

I can not get my DataTable to load the datas by a route in Api.php type POST.

I am using this DataTables: https://datatables.net/

Api.php

```php
Route::post('subredes/{username}/{token}', function($username, $token){
    $user = DB::table('usuarios')
                    ->where('token', $token)
                    ->value('username');
    $estado = DB::table('usuarios')
                    ->where('username', $username)
                    ->value('estado');  

    if(!empty(trim($user)) && $estado == 2){
        $query = DB::table('subredes as s')
            ->select('s.id', 's.ip', 's.gateway', 's.mask');

        return datatables()
            ->of($query)
            ->addColumn('btn','Actions.subredes')
            ->rawColumns(['btn'])
            ->toJson();
    }

});
```

Javascript

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#Subredes').DataTable({
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "language":{
            "url": "{{url('api/spanish')}}"
        },
        "destroy": true,
        "responsive": true,
        "serverSide":true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "{{url('api/subredes/'.auth()->user()->username.'/'.auth()->user()->token)}}",
            "type": "POST",
        },
        "columnDefs": [{
        "targets": 'no-sort',
        "orderable": false,
        "searchable": false,
        }],
        "columns":[
            {data: 'ip', name: 's.ip'},
            {data: 'gateway', name: 's.gateway'},
            {data: 'mask', name: 's.mask'},
            {data: 'btn'},
        ]
        });
    });
```

Error:

[image]

I suspect that it is because he did not give him the CSRF, but I do not know how to do it and I am not 100% sure that this is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that DataTables is making a GET request and you only allow POST. The error is in the ajax configuration: You have to replace `type` with `method` and it will send it as POST.

Source: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

The CSRF token will be your next problem. The simplest method would be to use GET instead of post (in the DataTables configuration and the Route configuration). Otherwise you will have to expose the token somewhere in your HTML (e.g. a meta tag) and send it with the request:

```js
    let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');
    //...
        "ajax": {
            "url": "{{url('api/subredes/'.auth()->user()->username.'/'.auth()->user()->token)}}",
            "method": "POST",
            "data": {
                _token: token,
        },
```

Comment: Right now I get a problem in the jquery that says: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Comment: I think it was at the time of assigning the value to the variable token use $ ('meta [name = csrf_token]'). attr ("content") and it works correctly, will there be any problem doing it this way?